# Arrays that are in variables and displaying them By class/for loop

Tags: php

This is my code: Right now as you can see you are only looking the last index. the `show_results` for example. First of all, the `$titleNamesArr` it's a simple variable that contains scraped information. Also the `$imageArr` , `$pathAarr` etc.. all the way to the `$details`. These variables contains each one of them exactly 20 scraped data information... so what i need is someone to guide me how can i display all the variables correctly.

---

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Main.php';
require_once 'crawling.php';

$titleNamesArr = $_SESSION['titleNames'];
$imageArr = $_SESSION['imageArr'];
$pathArr = $_SESSION['pathArr'];
$subtitle = $_SESSION['subtitle'];
$description = $_SESSION['descriptionCat'];
$details = $_SESSION['details'];
```

---

Ofcourse i can do it like that: But i am reapeating myself a lot, Imagine having 100 data.

```
 $card0 =new Main($titleNamesArr[0],$imageArr[0],$pathArr[0],$subtitle[0],$description[0],$details[0]);
    echo $card0->showingCards()."<br>"."<br>";

$card1 = new Main($titleNamesArr[1],$imageArr[1],$pathArr[1],$subtitle[1],$description[1],$details[1]);
    echo $card1->showingCards()."<br>"."<br>";

$card2 = new Main($titleNamesArr[2],$imageArr[2],$pathArr[2],$subtitle[2],$description[2],$details[2]);
    echo $card2->showingCards()."<br>"."<br>";
```

---

This is what i have tried so far. It is returning me 11 from the 20 results, of course somewhere i am wrong.

```
///// Showing the cards
    for($i=0; $i<=count($titleNamesArr); $i++)  {
        $card = new Main($titleNamesArr[$i], $imageArr[$i], $pathArr[$i], $subtitle[$i], $description[$i], $details[$i]);
        echo $card->showingCards() . "<br>" . "<br>";
        $i++;
    }
```

Anyone's advise ?

Comment: _how can i display all the variables correctly._ Well that depends upon a number of things, first of which is 1. How do you want them displayed. 2. What exactly does CORRECTLY mean to you?

Comment: let's say for example display the results with a foreach statement or with a for loop (avoid the repeat method).. the correct way is different from one person to another..

Comment: _the correct way is different from one person to another_ Thats my point. You didn't really make much effort to tell us what YOU consider a correct way

Comment: i consider a correct way to be by using the foreach or forloop statement. YOU ?

Comment: Do you need to keep the `$card0` and `$card1` etc etc objects or are they just to be used in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the unnecessary `$i++;` the loop will work correctly. The loop counter is already in the for statement.

You could also fix the unnecessary literal concatenation and make `"<br>" . "<br>";` into `"<br><br>";`

Like so:

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($titleNamesArr); $i++)  {
    $card = new Main($titleNamesArr[$i], $imageArr[$i], $pathArr[$i], $subtitle[$i], $description[$i], $details[$i]);
    echo $card->showingCards() . "<br><br>";
    //$i++;
}
```